# Implement iAd in Spritekit Game With Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad

I can't seem to be able to load iAd banners in a Swift app within a SpriteKit game... Been googleing it for a while and nothing.... It simply won't make the network call to load the ad... I have implemented all of the necessary calls and set the delegate with no luck...

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    println("Failed to load ad")

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    println("Loaded Ad")

    //now show the ad
    //set position off-screen
    banner.frame.origin.y = screenHeight

    banner.hidden = false



}

func createAds() {


    //create ad to allow it to load
    let adBanner = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 50))
    adBanner.delegate = self
    adBanner.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, 25)
    adBanner.hidden = true


    //add to screen
    self.view?.addSubview(adBanner)


    println("Created Ad")


}


func hideAds() {


}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

then I simply call the createAds() method when the game starts which then shows a white rectangle at the top of the screen ("0,0", "quote, quote, is it zero zero a the top"?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this (in GameViewController.swift):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!,    willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("error!")
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
}
```

You also need to import iAd
and add `ADBannerViewDelegate` to the GameViewController class